# Internationalizing Flutter apps with flavors

Tags: flutter, internationalization

I've internationalized my app using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package and it has two different languages. The app also has two different flavors. I want to use different translation files for a language in each flavor. I mean, I want to have `app_en.arb` file for flavor A and another one for flavor B with different texts. How can I have different translation files for each flavor?